# Multiple Reference headings

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, subdividing, apa6

I am new to latex. I have all my references contains in `bibfile.bib`. However, I have formatted my document to output separate bibliographies after each section. In my main tex file I have:

```
\usepackage[section]{chapterbib}
\usepackage{apacite}

\include{section1}
\include{section2}
\include{section3}
```

In each `section#.tex` file, at the end, I have:

```
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{bibfile}
```

I am not using biblatex or natbib or anything else. Everything works perfectly, *except* each reference section starts like this:

[image: http://f.cl.ly/items/28422m222H1m2y3Z330v/Screen%20shot%202013-01-31%20at%204.07.07%20AM.png]

I would like to get rid of these headers entirely, and perhaps use a `\subsection` so that the reference section is numbered properly. Or at least, get rid of two of the three "Reference" headings...

I see several similar threads, but they are using different packages and I can't seem to figure this out. I know I should be able to remap the Reference header, but I can't find a solution that works.

Note: `\renewcommand{\refname}{}` doesn't work. Not only does it leave a big space in place of the reference header, it doesn't get rid of the last `*References`

Comment: Please post a short, complete example code that reproduces the problem. Without that it will be difficult for anyone to help you.

Comment: Each `\bibliography` command prints such a title.  Have a look at the following FAQ answer about [multiple bibliographies](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=multbib)

Comment: @AndrewSwann hmm i think that's for using multiple bibliography files, no? I only have one .bib file

Comment: As Ian Thompson, said we need more details of what you are doing, to avoiding guessing too much.  Providing a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) would be best.  The FAQ I provided, links to another question about [bibliographies per chapter](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=chapbib), which also applies to other sectional units.

Comment: @AndrewSwann I have already edited my question, but please let me know if this is not sufficient

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the apacite package documentation, using the sectionbib option of chapterbib is not recommended.

The solution is to use the sectionbib option of apacite in conjunction with chapterbib, i.e.

```
\usepackage[sectionbib]{apacite}
\usepacakge{chapterbib}
```

then simply print your bibliography in each section as usual:

```
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{bibfile}
```